# Value not displaying in a cell vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a simple piece of code as below.For both the lines values display in vba console, which means the logic is working. But when I try to show them on excel, the value doesn't display for `wsA.Range("C7").Value` . I am not sure what am I doing wrong. Can anyone help?

```
wsA.Range("C4").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Output Sheet").Range("B4").Value
'added logic to tranfer date of assessment
Debug.Print wsA.Range("C4").Value

  wsA.Range("C7").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Output Sheet").Range("B8").Value
    Debug.Print wsA.Range("B7").Value
    Debug.Print wsA.Range("C7").Value
```

Comment: The line `wsA.Range("C7").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Output Sheet").Range("B8").Value` works fine providing `wsA` is set to valid worksheet and the currently active workbook has a sheet called "Output Sheet".  When the code runs is the active workbook the correct one?  Is `wsA` defined properly?  Does `Debug.Print` return anything when applied to the value in the "Output Sheet"?  Does the `wsA` target cell have any custom cell formatting (does the value appear in the formula bar, but not in the cell?)